# jQuery UI, launch bounce effect after fadeIn, cannot get it to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 4 pictures "Goog", they are hidden. I want to fadeIn two of them, and then launch Bounce, like second effect. But I can do it only with button, not in fadeIn complete function:

**jsfiddle**: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Rockietm/hszcnszj/)

```
<input type="button" id="bouncebutton" value="Click to insert first letter 'G' and third 'o'"/>

<div id="logos">
    <img src="https://picoolio.net/images/2017/01/14/1f2270.png" style="display: none;" /><!--G-->
    <img src="https://picoolio.net/images/2017/01/14/2407ae.png" style="display: none;" /><!--o-->
    <img src="https://picoolio.net/images/2017/01/14/3184af.png" style="display: none;" /><!--o-->
    <img src="https://picoolio.net/images/2017/01/14/4422f7.png" style="display: none;" /><!--g-->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    "use strict";

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("#logos > img:odd").fadeIn(5000, function () {
            // bot these works wrong (toggle works Ok with button , see example below) :
            //$("#logos > img:even").effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 300);
            //$("#logos > img:even").toggle("bounce", { times: 3 }, "slow");
        });


        // here with button it works Ok.. :
        $("#bouncebutton").on("click", function () {
            // this works wrong (something with 'bounce' syntax?..)
            // $("#logos > img:even").effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 300);

            // here it works like a charm (on click), but works wrong in fadeIn delegate(
            $("#logos > img:even").toggle("bounce", { times: 3 }, "slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

jQuery is jquery-3.1.1.min.js

jQuery UI jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom

**Upd.: Resolved.** My stupid mistake - there are two pictures, and toggle launched twice for every of them. I added wasLaunched flag, not the ideal solution I know:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    "use strict";

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        var wasToggled = false;
        jQuery("#logos > img:odd").fadeIn(8000, function () {
            if (!wasToggled) {
                jQuery("#logos > img:even").toggle("bounce", { times: 3 }, 1500);
                wasToggled = true;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: a jsfiddle would be a great help, but try using `$("#logos > img:nth-child(even)")...` instead of `$("#logos > img:even")` in your jquery selectors

Comment: Sam, thank You for answer!

Have tried, same result. Updated code with jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/Rockietm/hszcnszj/

I suggest my problem is with "bounce", it toggles twice on load..
https://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/